# NextJS - react-springy-parallax doesn't work

Tags: next.js

I'm trying to use [react-springy-parallax](https://github.com/drcmda/react-springy-parallax) in my NextJS project, but whenever I want to use it, I get the following error message:

> Fetch API cannot load webpack://%5Bname%5D_%5Bchunkhash%5D/./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js?. URL scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS request.

Is this is a limitation to `react-springy-parallax` on NextJS?

Here is the example code I put in my `index.js` component:

```
<Parallax ref='parallax' pages={3}>
  <Parallax.Layer offset={0} speed={0.5}>
    <span>Layers can contain anything</span>
  </Parallax.Layer>
</Parallax>
```

It seems the problem has something to do with a *CORS* issue and I don't know exactly how to approach a solution to this problem.

Comment: Check this thread: https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/6374. Your bug is likely related to nextjs than react-springy-parallax.

Comment: Try updating to the latest version of Next.js

Answer (score 0):

I've read that this has nothing to do with NextJS in particular. After React 16.8.0 and up, I read that I have to use the `useRef` function.

Solution:

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react'
[...]
const parallax = useRef( 'parallax' )
[...]
<Parallax ref={ parallax } pages={3}>

    <Parallax.Layer offset={0} speed={0.5} onClick={ () => parallax.current.scrollTo(1) }>

        <span>Layers can contain anything</span>

    </Parallax.Layer>

</Parallax>
```

Answer (score 0):

Next Js has no problem with next Js. First initialize  a variable to use as useRef

```
const parallax = useRef(null!)
```

Then you can start creating the parallax component and you should use the `ParallaxLayer` component instead of `Parallax.Layer` component

```
<Parallax pages={3} ref={parallax}>
  <ParallaxLayer offset={0} speed={0.5}>
    <span>Layers can contain anything</span>
  </ParallaxLayer>
</Parallax>
```

This will solve the problem, if you need example, check out this code,
[parallax in next JS](https://github.com/harisankar01/article-app/blob/master/aa_app/pages/index.tsx)